# Securing data at rest in Kafka

Tags: security, encryption, apache-kafka

We are preparing for our first deployment of Kafka to production, and I'm wondering about the best way to implement data-at-rest security.

I've seen a few articles talking about end to end security/encryption (i.e., https://lenses.io/blog/2017/06/kafka-data-security/
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/10/transparent-end-end-security-apache-kafka-part-1/
https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/end-end-encryption-though-kafka-our-proof-concept), but we are not looking for end to end security as it runs within our internal network, just to secure the data at rest.

Which would be best approach? Disk encryption, filesystem-level encryption, a combination of both? Which would be the impact on performance?

What about Zookeeper? Do we need to encrypt Zookeeper's data as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your org. already using NavEncrypt, for HDFS encryption for instance, you may wanna look at https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/kafka_security.html#kafka_encryption_at_rest

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha. We are not, but we could certainly think about it

Comment: As far I know the Zookeeper is used only for the cluster coordination, not storing the messages themselves. According to my experience, disk encyption is directly supported by all major OS or cloud providers, so the least overhead. Encryption is usually much faster than disk IO, so the overhead is minimal (especially with HW support).